# Using 3NF in Laravel's ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent, entity-relationship, 3nf

I am trying to build a simple Laravel application. My data model looks like the following:

```
ENTITIES: 
Project, Requirements, ProjectRequirementStatus

RELATIONSHIPS:
A Project has many Requirements
A requirement belongs to many Projects as a "ProjectRequirement"
A "ProjectRequirement" has one ProjectRequirementStatus
A ProjectRequirementStatus belongs to many Projects

TABLES:
projects
requirements
project_requirements
project_requirement_statuses

MODELS:
Project, Requirements, ProjectRequirementStatus
```

My question IS:

Is it improper to create a model for a relationship class? In this case, I would need to create a `ProjectRequirement` model and define the relationship to the ProjectRequirementStatus class.

I'm confused because most of my pivot tables include IDs of the two tables they are joining in a Many to Many, and typically, no additional relationships.

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Are there "best practices" in terms of when a Model is created versus when it's not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Using the 3NF in Laravel, you do not have to make models for the relationships. Laravel provides the [Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) which will provide the relationships without having to make the pivot tables models.

The Eloquent ORM also provides you a way to access data on pivot tables. ([Defining The Inverse Of The Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))